# I have the error message in Pgadmin 4 like this

Tags: database, postgresql, pgadmin-4

[image]

I have a question, i running pgAdmin 4 in docker container, and i will create server and i got this error.
Can you help me to solved my problem.

Comment: It’s in a container so you probably haven’t exposed/bound the port so no connections can be made?

Comment: I agree with @SamiKuhmonen that it could be related to the port expose to localhost. But I suggest pasting the command that you had used to spin the container (or the docker-compose) for a more accurate answer.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: hi there, thank you for answer my question.
this problem is solved, problem my question is i'm forget this is server in Postgresql.
i'm add hostname: postgres and password:password .